# A weird connection between Topology and algebra

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, topological-rings

It is common for mathematicians to try and merge different structures which they find interesting. Topological groups and Topological rings are examples of this, where one defines a topology and a group (resp. ring) structure on the same underlying set, and requires that the group operations are continuous with respect to this tolology.

There are many different ways to define a Topology on a given group to achieve this, but if you take some collection of normal subgroups of a given group, and all their cosets as a subbase, the resulting topology produces a topological group. If you take a collection of ideals of a given ring, and all their 'cosets' as a subbase, the resulting topology produces a Topological ring.

In both these examples, an arbitrary collection of kernels of homomorphisms could be used to define a Topological structure that works nicely with the algebraic structure. Is this a coincidence? Does this work when trying to define topologies on other kinds of algebraic structure where the notion of a kernel makes sense? Is there some sort of underlying reason for this?

Comment: Maybe it's related to the notion initial topology "weakest topology that makes some functions continuous"? Since every normal group is corresponding to the function $f:G \to G/N$ and..

Comment: Unfortunately the vast majority of topological groups that are actually studied don't arise in this way. If you additionally want the topological group to be $T_1$ then this construction automatically gives discrete topology. And so very limited.

Comment: @freakish indeed, but it is still interesting (to me) that this construction does always produce a topological group

Comment: Well, you've picked a collection of subsets that make group multiplication continuous. Its sounds quite natural to me that subgroups will fit this well. Or more generally subobjects. Other than that I'm not sure what kind of answer you are looking for? Maybe it is interesting, but I don't see a proper question here...

Comment: By the way, these don't have to be kernels, i.e. those subgroups don't have to be normal for it to work.

Comment: @freakish the question is if this construction works for a general algebraic structure, i.e. does taking a collection of kernels of some object in a variety and turning it into a subbase in the described way always lead to a structure where the operations are continuous

Comment: The common language for "general algebraic structure" is the category theory. However objects in an arbitrary category do not have to be sets. And yet they still may have kernels and subobjects. Moreover even if objects are sets, subobjects do not have to be subsets. And so defining any topology on an arbitrary object is already a problematic idea. You may cover some algebraic structures with this idea: groups, rings, modules, etc. But the amount of algebraic structures we consider nowadays is just huge.